# App rejected in Google Play. Youtube API conflict?

Tags: android, youtube, admob

Ok. So we programmed this app with a tab redirecting to an official Youtube channel. The videos in it are entirely legal and we have all the permissions (actually the only copyrighted material is ours).

Google will reject it because "After a regular review, we have determined that your app downloads, monetizes, or otherwise accesses YouTube videos in violation of the YouTube Terms of Service or YouTube API Terms of Service. Accessing content, a product, or service in an unauthorized manner is a violation of the Developer Distribution Agreement, and is not allowed on Google Play"...

Is it for the, again, legal and free of any kind of alteration Admob code as banner in the tab bottom?? Any other reason??

Comment: So you are asking about Admob or Youtube? Is your app rejected? Be specific! In any case you can ask Google team for an appeal.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for legal interpretation of Google policy.

Comment: It IS rejected and Google denied the appeal without any explanation.

Comment: @FranJ.Girao is there any news? I'm facing the same problem! I got a notification, but i open the youtube video at the app

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about a programming problem

Answer (score 11):

You can put ads to the video list, all other places but the video screen where youtube videos playing can not have any kind of ads.

It is same for the web pages. Google says that if the visitor enters a webpage for watching a youtube video, you can't place ads, if the visitor's main reason to visit that page is something else and there is also a youtube video on the page then it is allowed to put ads. Also other web pages that doesn't include youtube videos can have ads on it. This is the rule.

So, put your ads only the places where there is no youtube video on it. This is the solution.

---

**Update:**
Please see the Youtube Terms of Service, Section 2. Commercial Use : https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms

> You agree not to use the YouTube API for any of the following
>   commercial uses unless You obtain YouTube's prior written approval:
>
> the sale of the YouTube API, API Data, YouTube audiovisual content or
>   related services, or access to any of the foregoing; the sale of
>   advertising, sponsorships, or promotions placed on or within the
>   YouTube audiovisual content or player; or the sale of advertising,
>   sponsorships, or promotions **on any page of the API Client containing
>   YouTube audiovisual content**, unless other content not obtained from
>   YouTube appears on the same page and is of sufficient value to be the
>   basis for such sales.

Comment: can you quote this from official doc?

Comment: @khurramengr I did it, please check.

Comment: what about download youtube videos? will banned too?

Comment: If you mean, you download the youtube videos, upload them to somewhere else (AWS or any other hosting company) and list them in your app without any relation to youtube, then I don't think it will be banned until any claim is done by the video owners. If any claim is made by the video owners, I think, it will be banned.